# iostat -k in Solaris (SunOS 5.10)

Tags: solaris, iostat

In Linux `iostat -k` displays `kB_read` `kB_wrtn` fields, which are total data read/written during the measured interval.

```
#iostat -k
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               0.59         3.69        10.46   12418161   35236147
```

Is there any possibility to display the same in Solaris?

Answer (score 0):

try iostat -xn... I think the output is similar to Linux.

Comment: I'm using 'iostat -xtc' for most statistics, which is the similar to your output, but it doesn't show 'kB_read' 'kB_wrtn'.

Answer (score 0):

`iostat -sndx 1` will produce this output:

```
                 extended device statistics              
 r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
 1.0    1.1   82.1    8.5  0.0  0.0    0.0    9.7   0   1 c2t0d0
36.9    0.6 4576.8   14.2  0.0  0.6    0.0   16.2   0  14 c2t1d0
 6.6    0.3  695.1   64.2  0.0  0.0    0.0    5.7   0   2 c2t2d0
 0.0    7.7    0.8 2438.0  2.1  1.0  270.4  128.0  33  33 c1t0d0
 0.0    7.8    0.8 2438.1  2.1  1.0  271.6  128.2  33  33 c1t0d1
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.1   0   0 c1t0d2


                 extended device statistics              
 r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
 0.0   85.0    0.0  360.5  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.4   0   1 c2t0d0
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t1d0
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t2d0
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c1t0d0
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c1t0d1
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c1t0d2

                 extended device statistics              
 r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t0d0
12.0  118.0   24.5  460.5  0.0  0.5    0.0    3.7   0  44 c2t1d0
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t2d0
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c1t0d0
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c1t0d1
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c1t0d2
```

The `1` argument specifies emitting an output set once per second.  Add a second numerical value to specify how many sets of output are emitted.  The first set out output is the I/O statistics since the counters were last reset, probably at boot.

Add `-z` to suppress rows with all zeros.

Add `-p` to see per-partition statistics.

Add `-I` to see raw counts instead of rate numbers. (Might only be Solaris 11)

Comment: Thanks, but not what I need.

Comment: @vasiliyrur What do you need?  The data's all there even if the column order is different.

Comment: I need KB (or MB, bytes, doesn't matter) read/written during interval. Not per second.
Your listing is similar to linux 'iostat -x' output. I need listing similar to linux 'iostat -k'

Comment: @vasiliyrur Did you try `-I`?  "Add `-I` to see raw counts instead of rate numbers."